# I have a visa, but my employer canceled our contract before I could move to Germany

Tags: germany, work-permit

It took 9 months for the embassy to prepare our visa and before that (almost 4 months before visa issuance) the company canceled the contract because of the long wait.

But, after a while, they called us from the embassy and gave us the visa and it's valid for 1 year. It's not a blue card visa, but the name of the company is on the visa.

So, my question is: Can I move to Germany now and look for another job or because of the name of the employer in the visa, might there be a problem at my arrival?

If I can move to Germany now, do I have to go and change my visa to a job seeker visa or I can just look for another job?

Comment: If you read the visa conditions carefully it will tell you whether this is a visa for this specific company or one that lets you work for any company.